# Why are there two app icons after installing on the android?

Tags: android, react-native

My app shows two app icons after installing it on android with React Native. Why is this happening? Any idea?

I am only using one `index.js`. I do not have an `index.android.js` and my version of React Native is `0.50.3`.

Answer (score 21):

My fault :( I have two activity in AndroidManifest.xml with:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Remove one and perfect :)

Comment: Remove one what? One activity, or one `<intent-filter>` tag?

Comment: Can we remove either one of them, or shall we remove one instead of another?

Comment: I think he had two activities with both having having the intent-filter. I had the same problem. I removed the intent-filter from one of the activities and it fixed the issue

Comment: You can remove only duplicate `<intent-filter>`, in case you have an `<activity>` for splash screen, remove `<intent-filter>` from main activity